# How can I switch two items while other sortable items are disabled and should not move using jQuery UI Sortable?

Tags: html, jquery, css

I want to be able to disable all items but two on my sortable jQuery UI so that I can switch those two item's position while those disabled items stays on its place. Doing this will make dragging and dropping easier if you just want two items to switch places. If you don't freeze all the other items and want to switch two item's places, it's easy to get lost where to put the last item because all of the other items moved.

[A example of that problem is on this Codepen](https://codepen.io/palekjram/pen/mdMLZQE). When I try to switch Bromine on the first column to Sulfur on the third column, it's hard to remember where the original position of Bromine and Sulfur automatically goes to the 1st column but not where Bromine was. So I have to constantly remember where every one is so I can rearrange them.

[In this Codepen](https://codepen.io/palekjram/pen/vYJjqpE), I have disabled sortable on all of the items but Sulfur and Bromine so that I can switch them easily. The problem is that when I drag Bromine to Sulfur's place, Sulfur doesn't go to Bromine's place but instead go to the next row on the 1st column and Sulfur is stuck on its place. So those disabled items are not actually frozen but will still move when they see an empty space at the bottom.

How can I make it so that those disabled items will not move so that Sulfur will automatically switch to Bromine's place when I drag it?

Here's the jQuery code that I'm using:

```
  $( function() {
    $( "#sortable1" ).sortable({
      items: "li:not(.ui-state-disabled)"
    });
    $( "#sortable1 li" ).disableSelection();
  } );
```

Comment: sortable isn't fit for purpose IMO

Comment: The reason for why `Sulfur` jumps to the other column is you are using a single `sortable` list and when an item is appeded to its old position, it jumps to the next position. jQuery UI looks like have no `position` option for the item that is being swapped out. One solution is that you can serialize the whole list when pick up an item, temporarily save current item's id and position. Then on release get the released item's `position`, move item at `position+1` to saved position. I could be wrong too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sortable` doesn't swap elements it just positions one element.
You can use `draggable` and `droppable` like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function () {
        var items;
        var firstItem;
        var secondItem;

        $(".list-item").draggable({
          revert: "invalid",
          revertDuration: 200,
          start: function () {
            firstItem = this;
            $(this).addClass("dragme");
          },
          stop: function () {
            $(this).removeClass("dragme");
          },
        });

        $(".list-item").droppable({
          hoverClass: "droponme",

          drop: function (event, ui) {
            items = $("#swap-list li");
            secondItem = this;
            var firstIndex = items.index(firstItem);
            var secondIndex = items.index(secondItem);

            if (firstIndex < secondIndex) {
              $(firstItem).insertAfter($(secondItem));
              if (firstIndex < 1) {
                $(secondItem).insertBefore($(items).get(firstIndex + 1));
              } else {
                $(secondItem).insertAfter($(items).get(firstIndex - 1));
              }
              $(firstItem).css({ left: 0, top: 0 });
            } else {
              if (secondIndex < 1) {
                $(firstItem).insertBefore($(items).get(secondIndex + 1));
              } else {
                $(firstItem).insertAfter($(items).get(secondIndex - 1));
              }
              $(secondItem).insertAfter($(items).get(firstIndex - 1));
              $(firstItem).css({ left: 0, top: 0 });
            }
          },
        });
      });
    </script>

    <style>
      #list {
        height: 200px;
        width: 350px;
        padding: 5px;
        background-color: blanchedalmond;
      }

      #swap-list {
        width: 300px;
        height: 100%;
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        zoom: 1;
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        flex-direction: column;
      }

      .list-item {
        margin: 0 5px 5px 5px;
        padding: 3px;
        flex: 0 0 auto;
        width: 32.333333%;
        cursor: grab;
        background-color: lightyellow;
        border: 1px dashed black;
      }

      .list-item:hover {
        background-color: #ffcdc4;
      }

      .list-item.droponme {
        background-color: rgb(169, 202, 136);
      }

      .list-item.dragme {
        background: rgb(212, 253, 171, 0.4);
        text-align: right;
        z-index: 100;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h3 class="docs">Specify which items are sortable:</h3>
    <div id="list">
      <ul id="swap-list"
        ><li class="list-item">Helium</li>
        <li class="list-item">Lithium</li>
        <li class="list-item">Beryllium</li>
        <li class="list-item">Boron</li>
        <li class="list-item">Carbon</li>
        <li class="list-item">Nitrogen</li>
        <li class="list-item">Oxygen</li>
        <li class="list-item">Fluorine</li>
        <li class="list-item">Neon</li>
        <li class="list-item">Sodium</li>
        <li class="list-item">Magnesium</li>
        <li class="list-item">Aluminium</li>
        <li class="list-item">Silicon</li>
        <li class="list-item">Phosphorus</li>
        <li class="list-item">Sulfur</li>
        <li class="list-item">Chlorine</li>
        <li class="list-item">Argon</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Right now it swaps instantly you can add animation effects.

**Note:** This is just a demo code.

Comment: This is very good. The only thing not working for me is when you swap anything to the very first block "Heluim". When you swap anything to the last block "Argon", it's still works well. What's the idea to make the first block not make the others move? Will it be a a lot more code to make it work?

Comment: I've fixed the code. check and let me know.

Comment: It's perfect now. Thank you!